# What mysql engine for huge amount of data (logging)?

Tags: mysql, logging, structure

What mysql engine would be best suited for handling huge amount (many rows) of (small) data? I talking about logging.

I'm thinking about logging whenever I do things on my page, like calling a function, calling a file and so on.

A tip of how I should structure the table is also appreciated.

Comment: So lots of writes and not many reads?

Comment: Kinda. You will be able to see the log in a specific page but the view count on that page would probably not be high.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Archive storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/archive-storage-engine.html) is geared toward storing logs, and is compressed.  It supports INSERT and SELECT only, no UPDATE or DELETE.  I have never used it, but it may fit your needs.

Comment: Will try and see if it fit my needs.